# why does my mesh glitch out like this while moving in edit mode?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, error

these are pictures of my mesh before and after I move it
does anybody know how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Disable Mesh symmetry XYZ ... top-right row next to a butterfly icon.